# how to open base64 image in light box

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I am trying to open a base 64 image code in light box is it possible or not ? i tried using fancy box light-box but it didn't worked. here is my code please suggest me any light-box and also tell me how to use that light-box with base 64 :-

```
    $SQL_img=mysql_query("select * from image_table");  

                      while($Get=mysql_fetch_array($SQL_img))
                      { 
                     ?>                   


        <? echo '<img src="data:image/gif;base64,' . $Get['p_image'] . '" width="238px" hight="256px" />'; ?>

                  <?
                     }
                  ?>    
--------------------------------WHOLE CODE----------------------------

Short code is enabled.

    <!-- Add jQuery library -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lightbox/lib/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Add mousewheel plugin (this is optional) -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lightbox/lib/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.6.pack.js"></script>

    <!-- Add fancyBox main JS and CSS files -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lightbox/source/jquery.fancybox.js?v=2.1.5"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="lightbox/source/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.5" media="screen" />

    <!-- Add Button helper (this is optional) -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="lightbox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.css?v=1.0.5" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lightbox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.js?v=1.0.5"></script>

    <!-- Add Thumbnail helper (this is optional) -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="lightbox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.css?v=1.0.7" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lightbox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js?v=1.0.7"></script>

    <!-- Add Media helper (this is optional) -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lightbox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-media.js?v=1.0.6"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            /*
             *  Simple image gallery. Uses default settings
             */

            $('.fancybox').fancybox();

            /*
             *  Different effects
             */

            // Change title type, overlay closing speed
            $(".fancybox-effects-a").fancybox({
                helpers: {
                    title : {
                        type : 'outside'
                    },
                    overlay : {
                        speedOut : 0
                    }
                }
            });

            // Disable opening and closing animations, change title type
            $(".fancybox-effects-b").fancybox({
                openEffect  : 'none',
                closeEffect : 'none',

                helpers : {
                    title : {
                        type : 'over'
                    }
                }
            });

            // Set custom style, close if clicked, change title type and overlay color
            $(".fancybox-effects-c").fancybox({
                wrapCSS    : 'fancybox-custom',
                closeClick : true,

                openEffect : 'none',

                helpers : {
                    title : {
                        type : 'inside'
                    },
                    overlay : {
                        css : {
                            'background' : 'rgba(238,238,238,0.85)'
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

            // Remove padding, set opening and closing animations, close if clicked and disable overlay
            $(".fancybox-effects-d").fancybox({
                padding: 0,

                openEffect : 'elastic',
                openSpeed  : 150,

                closeEffect : 'elastic',
                closeSpeed  : 150,

                closeClick : true,

                helpers : {
                    overlay : null
                }
            });

            /*
             *  Button helper. Disable animations, hide close button, change title type and content
             */

            $('.fancybox-buttons').fancybox({
                openEffect  : 'none',
                closeEffect : 'none',

                prevEffect : 'none',
                nextEffect : 'none',

                closeBtn  : false,

                helpers : {
                    title : {
                        type : 'inside'
                    },
                    buttons : {}
                },

                afterLoad : function() {
                    this.title = 'Image ' + (this.index + 1) + ' of ' + this.group.length + (this.title ? ' - ' + this.title : '');
                }
            });


            /*
             *  Thumbnail helper. Disable animations, hide close button, arrows and slide to next gallery item if clicked
             */

            $('.fancybox-thumbs').fancybox({
                prevEffect : 'none',
                nextEffect : 'none',

                closeBtn  : false,
                arrows    : false,
                nextClick : true,

                helpers : {
                    thumbs : {
                        width  : 50,
                        height : 50
                    }
                }
            });

            /*
             *  Media helper. Group items, disable animations, hide arrows, enable media and button helpers.
            */
            $('.fancybox-media')
                .attr('rel', 'media-gallery')
                .fancybox({
                    openEffect : 'none',
                    closeEffect : 'none',
                    prevEffect : 'none',
                    nextEffect : 'none',

                    arrows : false,
                    helpers : {
                        media : {},
                        buttons : {}
                    }
                });

            /*
             *  Open manually
             */

            $("#fancybox-manual-a").click(function() {
                $.fancybox.open('1_b.jpg');
            });

            $("#fancybox-manual-b").click(function() {
                $.fancybox.open({
                    href : 'iframe.html',
                    type : 'iframe',
                    padding : 5
                });
            });

            $("#fancybox-manual-c").click(function() {
                $.fancybox.open([
                    {
                        href : '1_b.jpg',
                        title : 'My title'
                    }, {
                        href : '2_b.jpg',
                        title : '2nd title'
                    }, {
                        href : '3_b.jpg'
                    }
                ], {
                    helpers : {
                        thumbs : {
                            width: 75,
                            height: 50
                        }
                    }
                });
            });


        });
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        .fancybox-custom .fancybox-skin {
            box-shadow: 0 0 50px #222;
        }

        body {
            max-width: 700px;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <p>
        <!--<img src="1_s.jpg" alt="" />-->
    <?    

    mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
    mysql_select_db('db_store');

       $SQL_img=mysql_query("select * from image_table");  


                      while($Get=mysql_fetch_array($SQL_img))
                      { 
                     ?>                   

       <?

        echo '<a href="data:image/gif;base64,' . $Get['p_image'] . '"><img src="data:image/gif;base64,' . $Get['p_image'] . '" width="238px" height="256px" /></a>';

        ?>

                  <?
                     }
                  ?>     

    </p>
```

Comment: you should use the same data-url for href (the a around the img).

Comment: I would usually do it like this: `echo '<a href="data:image/gif;base64,' . $Get['p_image'] . '"><img src="data:image/gif;base64,' . $Get['p_image'] . '" width="238px" hight="256px" /></a>'; `

Comment: my "soultion" should usually work with fancybox. But you must initialize fancybox with `$('a').fancybox();` in a script tag.

Comment: @jankal I apply what you say but when i click on image its opening in new tab not in lightbox.i provided whole code you can see above

Comment: @Fred-ii- first thing short code is enabled and second thing it saved with .php extension and i have provided whole code you now can see above.

Comment: @jankal Thank you dear you solution worked for me just now.... :D i missed the light box class in <a> tag

Comment: Wonderful. I will add this as an answer later. Currently on the go.

Answer (score 0):

I would usually do it like this:

```
echo '<a class="fancybox" href="data:image/gif;base64,' . $Get['p_image'] . '"><img src="data:image/gif;base64,' . $Get['p_image'] . '" width="238px" hight="256px" /></a>';
```

But you now could intialize fancybox bound to the . Or just let it like this.

But I recommend to read the MIME-Type from the file itself. Its no good, when you specify the MIME-Type staticly in the URL.

Hope it helps ;)